# How could Alex (Seaplane) finish the game if none gave him the jewel?

Tags: plot-explanation, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle

In "Jumanji: Welcome to the jungle", when the four players Spencer, Martha, Anthony and Bethany joined the game, they were welcomed by Nigel who provide them a special jewel for breaking the **Jumanji curse**, sending them on a mission to return it to its place.

**[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji:_Welcome_to_the_Jungle)**

> The big-game hunter, Russel Van Pelt, wants to obtain a jewel, the "Jaguar's Eye," allowing him to manipulate Jumanji's animals.  To escape the game, the players must return it to an enormous jaguar statue and call out "Jumanji."

**Does this mean that Alex** (the fifth player, 20 years in game) **did not have a chance to escape at all and his only option was to wait for other players to join?**

Comment: Do we know he didn't get a gem? He said he couldn't make any further progress on his own so he must have been working towards something.

Comment: But if he had one, it is a game changer. They would have 2 gems and trick the bad guy easily. Or it wouldn't matter if one is lost - they would not risk to  go back with the helicopter, losing a life bar for it.

Comment: may be he lost it in the first place and, later it was given back to the team. Dont know, he never said he had the gem

Comment: I'm having a really hard time believing there were plot holes in Jumani.

Answer (score 2):

There was never any mention of whether he had a gem. It seems like all new groups of players receive a gem on starting the game, though. We see that the gem the new players have falls out of the helicopter from Fridge's bag. It's conceivable that's part of the game and Seaplane's gem fell out on an earlier run. But it's never explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible that the players will only receive the gem when they are all present in the game given that you can't complete the game until they are all there so there is no point in having the gem. In fact, its probably better that Seaplane didn't have it at the beginning because there was a bigger chance that it would have been stolen/lost before the other characters even arrived!

Answer (score 0):

I just finished after not watching it for years but I started with the original one first. And this time I seen a lot I didn't notice that connected the movies. But as for the question I do not think Alex could've finished without gravestone getting the jewel for him. Unless the chopper doesn't break when he's flying or if it does if he can find a way to manueaver the heard and land and fix it then he could've flown to the jag and placed his gem on top of the statue.

But I do see some people saying there is no way Alex could've got a gem of gravestone and then got one later. And he definetly could've, that's just how video games work lol. He could've lost his to the bad guys , but the bad guys don't actualy win the game and escape or nothing. So the story could've just been on hold until gravestone and then joined Wich is what happened.

I did have an issue with how the game just ended up in the school basement and not at Alan's house..with no explanation.

gripes and side notes:  I'd just like to mention I get the board game turning into a digital console game for the times.... but I think they could've done a better job showing it. Like the kid just threw it to the side for one second and the game new to transform. I mean unless we saying jumanji is just that magical and smart then ok I understand. But since it was locked away in a chest in the old movie I don't think they intended for it to be all knowing and smart or anything. I thought they were aiming more for a game that basically tried to trick kids into playing and adults couldn't hear the drums unless they were playing as kids then grew up. But it's Kindve like the new ones remove the dark Erie parts. But eh idk, like I said it's fine and they did a good job with the switch from stuff happening in our world from the game to taking and putting everyone in the game. But a cool part was the fact that other people had actually seen stuff comming out the game like the aunt and the cop even tho they don't remeber it at the end. One of my biggest pet leaves but I totally get it is that the kids didn't remeber anything. But I'm glad Alan And Sarah remeber. Oh lastly lol I'm super happy Sarah actualy atleast tried to tell people what happen they just didn't belive her.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  You appear to be saying that there's no way Alex could have escaped until the others showed up, because he wasn't given the jewel when he arrived.  This is what the question is asking, but you don't really explain _why_ that should be the case, you just seem to assume it and go on from there.  (Your second paragraph even admits that he _could_ have received a gem, so you need to explain how you know he didn't.)  You should also trim out the last paragraph, since those comments don't belong in an answer to this question.

Answer (score -2):

### Spoiler Alerts! This is an attempt to decode if all players could receive a Jaguar Jewel and if played with only one person could the player win playing single player mode and if Jumanji is a good or evil game to play.

**Let's get started.**

After watching the movie it seems Jumanji is not Really a Single player game and only one player gets the Jaguar jewel. Let me try to explain.

When the four kids turn on the game they see the Characters to choose from, Fridge asks Spencer which character he should choose. Spencer replies "I don't know, I don't think it matters that much".

As Fridge tries to play Seaplane McDonald (the first Avatar to choose from) he is unable due to the fact that Alex has already selected Seaplane.
Fridge then picks the very next character and so on.

Next scenes shows that Jumanji starts to suck in Spencer first even though it was Fridge that selected the next character. That's because Jumanji needs Dr Bravestone to start the Game. Then Ruby Roundhouse then Mouse Finbar. 
Finbar is selected last probably because of his character's unimportance to the game.

The four fall from the sky then land on the ground close together. Then they are chased by Hippos which they escape but not before one of the hippos eats Dr. Shelly played by Jack Black. (Ok First level is the easiest??) and the game starts.

There they are met by Nigel who is their greeter to the game. He greets Dr. Bravestone and the crew and drops them at a checkpoint and hands Dr. Brownstone the Jumanji map and the Jaguar jewel and recites in verse Return the Jewel and lift the Curse. If you wish to leave the game. You must save Jumanji and call out its name. ( The game may be a bit Narcissist, pun intended) and is to begin with Dr. Bravestone leading the way. Ok, So let's look further into this. The Game wants to be played and also is set up for five players .

It appears only Dr Bravestone can get the Jaguar jewel and Start the game yet the game makes Seaplane the first character to choose from that Alex has already picked.This further illustrates the games full intention of multi players and this is why Alex cant advance to get out of the game until the game is won or he dies. (More on this later). He needs at least one more Character and it has to be Dr. Bravestone since he is the only one that can get the jewel and start the Game. It takes at least 2 players to Win the game and Dr. Bravestone would need to be selected first or you may end up stuck there like Alex for 20 years.

My reasoning is when they arrive at the transportation shed. They get in the Chopper and rockets are fired and the blast dislodges a part that controls pitch and yaw. This is where you need at least one more player to win this level and advance to the next level. One to fly and one to fix the chopper. And the good Dc. Bravestone is ( the only one that gets a jewel and has no Weaknesses) and he is the one that repairs the helicopter and they progress to the next level.

Now I know what your thinking. What about Dr. Shelly Oberon? This is the only character that can read the map! Or Mouse Finbar who carries the backpack and defangs the Snake or Ruby Roundhouse that distracts and beats the crap out of the guards at the transportation shed?

I guess my logic relies heavily on that Dr. Bravestone with no fear and having no weakness and Smolders would just navigate without a map in Jumanji until he figured it out. He would already have the backpack presumably if Mouse didn't enter the game at the same time and could probably do the other characters actions single handedly since all NPC's talk to him and he is one of the Two Main Characters in the game. It finally falls down who the second Avatar is to say how difficult it would be to Win the game with just 2 players.

My conclusion is, Dr Bravestone is the only player that can get the gem and start the game because he is the main character and that the Game is possible to win with any other character that plays.( Kinda of like how hard you want the game to be by picking a weaker character).  P.s I also think when Alex started his part, (When he first gets sucked in the game).

The game put Alex in the middle of the game map were his Character would be the most useful. Why place him at the beginning if he can not get the gem and start the game. Alex plays the game were he is supposed to be useful and plays alone and dies twice but learns the game as he plays  Since players only have three lives Jumanji only put 3 flying aircrafts to use.

I feel Jumanji used its game power to trick Alex to try the hot air balloon first and the plane second. Knowing one  it would kill his first two lives and second eventually the other players would join the game and the helicopter is the only way to the next level and Jumanji doesn't want a key component to be destroyed and keeps the pilot alive.

I believe Jumanji does want the players to play so killing them wouldn't help the game and that if the players are unable to advance play and win alone that is when Jumanji would pause the game (sort of) and put the fear of sudden death in Alex or any lone player and then shows Alex the safe zone of the game where Jumanji had also shown Alan Parrish when he could go no further in his game and helps Alan Parrish build a safe zone and keeps Alan and Alex both safe for the next 26 and 20 years respectively in order to keep them alive so they can help the rest of the players get to the next level when the game could move forward in order for the players to win the game.Or that Alan had been there so long he found the safezone and built his place that way.

Though  its space/ time operates differently in Jumanji so I prefer to lean towards Jumanjis game design.  And I also feel Jumanji would allow  Alan or Alex or any player to leave from the safezone which would endanger them and possibly kill them but they could not progress in the game. That seems fair to me.

The bazaar may be a dangerous place but it may have been close to the safezone and that is why and how Alex knew about the underground passage way through its Booby traps and how to avoid the baddies at the Bizaar. All designed by Jumanji and it helped the good guys. That the lower levels are dangerous yet Alan and Alex had a lot of time to learn about the lower levels and that it would not help them progress to the next level so why go there if they really can die.

My thought is Jumanji is a Multi player Adventure other dimensional space/time entity game. That if played with all five players from the beginning some people might actually die and will continue to die until the game is won or can advance any further and without the Avatars to complete the game then Jumanji may actually keep the other players alive/safe until more players join the game so it can continue to offer the chance to win at the expense of you dieing.

Ok sounds good yet I'm still not sure if Jumanji is good or evil. Seems a bit of both. Until the next movie comes out we will probably never know.  Thanks Everyone!! I hope this was helpful. Let me know what you think .I am not an editor. I apologize for this appalling whatever this is letter. If anyone wants to leave a plus comment. Or add to this Smolder  please.

Comment: Welcome to Movies and TV. please consider [editing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/91927/edit) your answer to include paragraphs. in it's current form the  single block of text is hard to read

Comment: Even after so many edits, it's still look like a big chunk of blob, kindly split into meaningful paragraphs.